# D3 Arrows on Non-Circular Nodes

Tags: d3.js

I found this example on creating arrows that connect to circular nodes.

[arrows on links in d3js force layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568313/arrows-on-links-in-d3js-force-layout)

Is it possible to have arrows that connect to other shapes, like triangles and squares?  I'd like the arrow to touch the edge of the shape.